# Deauthenticate ALL wlan networks/clients in range

Tags: network, wifi, wireless, aircrack-ng

I need to deauthenticate all clients in all networks within the range of my wlan-adapter. Aireplay-ng allows only to focus a single network. Are there any programs or scripts i can use for this purpose?

Comment: hmmmmm.... this begs the question .... why ?

Comment: I am currently working on a wireless pentesting certification. Doing the deauthentication automatically would make things ways more easy.

Comment: Unfortunately questions about product (e.g. program or script) recommendations are not on topic. Perhaps if you could edit your question so it is more about how to do it and not about what software to use it would be on topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a script called "mass-deauth"

https://github.com/m33b0/mass-deauth